# MySQL MIN() + 1 row

Tags: mysql

I am running a SELECT query to get data from MySQL

```
SELECT
    MIN(datetime) as created,
    MAX(datetime) as updated,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'update' AND contact_name <> 'System' THEN 1 END) as replies,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'update' AND (contact_name * 1 = contact_name) THEN 1 END) as customer_replies
```

and it's working great, but I want to also get the next row after `MIN(datetime)`

Is it possible to do something like `MIN()+1`?

Comment: `Is it possible to do something like MIN()+1?` No it is not.. You can do something like `SELECT datetime FROM your_table  ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT 1,1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which gives the second lowest value:

```
SELECT
    MIN(datetime) as created_second_minimum 
FROM TableName
ORDER BY datetime
LIMIT 1,1;
```

When we use LIMIT n it returns the first n lines, when LIMIT n,m it returns m lines after the first n lines (which are not returned). In our example it does not return the first line and returns only the second one. As we have ordered the query by datetime the second line is the second oldest.

Comment: can i keep it all in the same query? I'm getting all the data in a single query